# Time ticker with React

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I'm building a component that renders the elapsed time from a given date. The date is a timestamp, for example, `1600836722`.

Here is what I have so far:

```js
const FORMAT_PATTERN = "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss";

export default function Timer({ dateCreated }) {
  const [hours, setHours] = useState(0);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const orderTimestamp = Moment.unix(dateCreated);
    setStartTime(Moment(orderTimestamp, FORMAT_PATTERN));
  }, [dateCreated]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      const now = Moment(Date.now());

      const difference = Moment.duration(
        Moment(now, FORMAT_PATTERN).diff(startTime)
      );

      setHours(Math.floor(difference.asHours())); // this is so that 1 day, 12 hours will be 34 hours
      setMinutes(Moment.utc(now.diff(startTime)).format("mm"));
      setSeconds(Moment.utc(now.diff(startTime)).format("ss"));
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [hours, minutes, seconds]);

  return hours && seconds && minutes ? (
    <Typography>{[hours, minutes, seconds].join(":")}</Typography>
  ) : null;
}
```

It works, displays the time just fine but there will be multiple components on the same page that track the elapsed time and my approach does not seem the most optimized. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you be more specific why do you think it is not optimized? Or do you have any actual performance issue? Such generic thought can be answered many ways from "it may be perfectly OK for your usage" to "oh god rewrite to vanilla JS, React is not the most optimized framework itself!" :)

Comment: I think that the multiple calls to Moment.duration() every second, from 10 of these timers will get overwhelming for browsers running on slower computers.

Comment: why do you think it will get overwhelming compared to the rest of the setInterval handler? Do you have some benchmark?

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be simplified much further into something like this. The value you render is dependent only on the current time.

You do not require multiple states since the `hours`, `seconds`, `days`--  what have you -- all else could just be derived from the `Date.now()`(date right now) .

```
function calculateTimeLeft() {
  const year = new Date().getFullYear();
  const difference = +new Date(`${year}-10-1`) - +new Date();
  let timeLeft = {};

  if (difference > 0) {
    timeLeft = {
      days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
      minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
      seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
    };
  }

  return timeLeft;
}

export default function App() {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = React.useState(calculateTimeLeft());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(id);
    };
  });

  const timerComponents = Object.keys(timeLeft).map(interval => {
    if (!timeLeft[interval]) {
      return;
    }

    return (
      <span>
        {timeLeft[interval]} {interval}{" "}
      </span>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <span>Time's up!</span>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

You could see the working example here :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t86icp

Comment: I'll give it a go. Thanks, @Prateek Thapa!